# Display more lines in Windows Media Center TV guide

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-center

The TV guide in Windows Media Center only shows 7 lines.  The font is massive and it is a real pain having to scroll so much to compare channels and see what is on.

[image]

Does anyone have a fix to change the font size and display more lines at once?  If there was just the option to decrease the font size throughout Windows Media Center - I'd take it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The patch and procedure to increase the number of lines described here:
[**Hacking Windows 7 Media Center:** Increasing the Default Number of Rows in the EPG](http://www.hack7mc.com/2009/12/increasing-the-default-number-of-rows-in-the-epg.html)

[image: Patched W7 MCE screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

The hack in accepted **Answer** is no longer available for download.
In spite of many other video media players I have tried, I like how WMC PVR features work... like record the next episodes with many criteria for auto-delete...

Your *best bet* is to use the  [Resource Hacker tool.](http://www.angusj.com/)

Open  **Microsoft.MediaCenter.Shell.dll** in your resource editor (prefix Microsoft is truncated in older  x32 versions) and browse to ...
HTML > ... EPG.MCML file. Inside **search** for key words in the following lines and edit the values as described:

Name=”InitialGridPosition” Left=”FilterButton,1,1″ Right=”Parent,1,-53″ Top=”FilterButton,0, –44
Name=”InitialGridPosition” Left=”FilterButton,1,1″ Right=”Parent,1,-53″ Top=”FilterButton,0, **-134**

Set Target=”[FilterButtonLayout.Bottom.Offset]” Value=“493”
Set Target=”[FilterButtonLayout.Bottom.Offset]” Value=“**580**”

Set Target=”[Table.VisibleRowCapacity]” Value=“7”
Set Target=”[Table.VisibleRowCapacity]” Value=“**11**”

Font FontName=”global://comm:LightFontFace” FontSize=“48”
Font FontName=”global://comm:LightFontFace” FontSize=“**0**”

SAVE FILE
Then open WMC

[image]

Open Resource Hacker> Open File> C:\Windows\ehome\Microsoft.MediaCenter.Shell.dll

Make above edits and If you want to make font smaller Search Font > change size to 10 or whatever F3 (repeat)

... until prompted to Compile (yes)> tab to left column and repeat...(search ..."font" ..edit value F3 ...etc.
 There are dozens of locations in many HTML files.

When searching beyond one HTML file to the next , after an edit you may be prompted to **Compile text** bu then F3 stops working until you ^f find text again then F3....  It's not very elegant code.
Then Press SAVE Icon.

Comment: Tony: If you can get inside WMC, is there a way to make it work with Windows10?

Comment: Unfortunately it no longer works even on Win7,8.1 with the media content server now defunct for the TV Guide

Comment: Thanks, but if I understand you, perhaps you're not in the UK? My WMC on WIN7 is working fine in the UK at present - the TV guide is almost always up-to-date for all the regular channels.

Comment: https://www.howtogeek.com/258695/how-to-install-windows-media-center-on-windows-10/